# How to send email contact us form in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email, mailto

As i have build the form and now i want the information directly to my mail inbox, but when client click on send the mailto option comes from the default mailing side , How can i get mail direct on my email when the client fill the contact us form as the code is bellow, and the link of the page is [contact us link](http://azuresolutionz.com/ContactUs.html)

```
        <form class="well form-horizontal"  action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend class="ContactUsHeading">Contact Us !</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
           <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
      <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>  
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
      <input name="phone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->



    <!-- Text input-->



    <!-- Select Basic -->


    <!-- Text input-->



    <!-- Text input-->


    <!-- radio checks -->
     <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Your</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="Company" value="yes" /> Company
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="company" value="no" /> Individual
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

    <!-- Text area -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Success message -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: any backend code to show?

Comment: not backend code as u can see in the link

Comment: then how are you sending email using jquery?

Comment: yes using the jquery and as u can see in the form action="mailto:abc@xyz.com"

Comment: Do you want the user to send the email via email software on their nown computer, or do you want your site to send it for them? If the latter, you need server side code and to PST the info from the Form back to your server. Is this MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: yes i want my site to send them for me directly , i do not want user to send via email software. when the client click on send button the info should come directly to my mailbox. @mason the web is not mvc

Comment: Is this Web Forms, or is this MVC? You tagged this as ASP.NET, but there are multiple frameworks in ASP.NET.

Comment: this is form as u can clearly see the code and the link